# html href link showing instead of title php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For some reason the related products on one of my woocommerce sites have started showing the full HTML Link instead of the product title.

I've narrowed it down to being an issue with the theme as the title show properly when the theme is switched. I've also tried removing all my custom CSS and deactivating all the plugins.

Here is the code for my related.php

```
    <?php

// Disable direct call
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit; }


/* Theme setup section
-------------------------------------------------------------------- */

if ( !function_exists( 'kingler_theme_template_related_theme_setup' ) ) {
    add_action( 'kingler_theme_action_before_init_theme', 'kingler_theme_template_related_theme_setup', 1 );
    function kingler_theme_template_related_theme_setup() {
        kingler_theme_add_template(array(
            'layout' => 'related',
            'mode'   => 'blog',
            'need_columns' => true,
            'need_terms' => true,
            'title'  => esc_html__('Related posts /no columns/', 'kingler-theme'),
            'thumb_title'  => esc_html__('Medium square image (crop)', 'kingler-theme'),
            'w'      => 370,
            'h'      => 370
        ));
        kingler_theme_add_template(array(
            'layout' => 'related_2',
            'template' => 'related',
            'mode'   => 'blog',
            'need_columns' => true,
            'need_terms' => true,
            'title'  => esc_html__('Related posts /2 columns/', 'kingler-theme'),
            'thumb_title'  => esc_html__('Medium square image (crop)', 'kingler-theme'),
            'w'      => 370,
            'h'      => 370
        ));
        kingler_theme_add_template(array(
            'layout' => 'related_3',
            'template' => 'related',
            'mode'   => 'blog',
            'need_columns' => true,
            'need_terms' => true,
            'title'  => esc_html__('Related posts /3 columns/', 'kingler-theme'),
            'thumb_title'  => esc_html__('Medium square image (crop)', 'kingler-theme'),
            'w'      => 370,
            'h'      => 370
        ));
        kingler_theme_add_template(array(
            'layout' => 'related_4',
            'template' => 'related',
            'mode'   => 'blog',
            'need_columns' => true,
            'need_terms' => true,
            'title'  => esc_html__('Related posts /4 columns/', 'kingler-theme'),
            'thumb_title'  => esc_html__('Medium square image (crop)', 'kingler-theme'),
            'w'      => 370,
            'h'      => 370
        ));
    }
}

// Template output
if ( !function_exists( 'kingler_theme_template_related_output' ) ) {
    function kingler_theme_template_related_output($post_options, $post_data) {
        $show_title = true; //!in_array($post_data['post_format'], array('aside', 'chat', 'status', 'link', 'quote'));
        $parts = explode('_', $post_options['layout']);
        $style = $parts[0];
        $columns = max(1, min(12, empty($post_options['columns_count']) 
                                    ? (empty($parts[1]) ? 1 : (int) $parts[1])
                                    : $post_options['columns_count']
                                    ));
        $tag = kingler_theme_in_shortcode_blogger(true) ? 'div' : 'article';

        if ($columns > 1) {
            ?><div class="<?php echo 'column-1_'.esc_attr($columns); ?> column_padding_bottom"><?php
        }
        ?>
        <<?php kingler_theme_show_layout($tag); ?> class="post_item post_item_<?php echo esc_attr($style); ?> post_item_<?php echo esc_attr($post_options['number']); ?>">

            <div class="post_content">
                <?php if ($post_data['post_video'] || $post_data['post_thumb'] || $post_data['post_gallery']) { ?>
                <div class="post_featured">
                    <?php
                    kingler_theme_template_set_args('post-featured', array(
                        'post_options' => $post_options,
                        'post_data' => $post_data
                    ));
                    get_template_part(kingler_theme_get_file_slug('templates/_parts/post-featured.php'));
                    ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if ($show_title) { ?>
                    <div class="post_content_wrap">
                        <?php
                        if (!isset($post_options['links']) || $post_options['links']) { 
                            ?><h5 class="post_title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url($post_data['post_link']); ?>"><?php kingler_theme_show_layout($post_data['post_title']); ?></a></h5><?php
                        } else {
                            ?><h5 class="post_title"><?php kingler_theme_show_layout($post_data['post_title']); ?></h5><?php
                        }
                        //kingler_theme_show_layout($reviews_summary);
                        if (!empty($post_data['post_terms'][$post_data['post_taxonomy_tags']]->terms_links)) {
                            ?><div class="post_info post_info_tags"><?php echo join(', ', $post_data['post_terms'][$post_data['post_taxonomy_tags']]->terms_links); ?></div><?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>  <!-- /.post_content -->
        </<?php kingler_theme_show_layout($tag); ?>>    <!-- /.post_item -->
        <?php
        if ($columns > 1) {
            ?></div><?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Also a link to a live example if needed http://www.omni-techinfo.com/index.php/product/ad-blue-grundfos-pump/

Comment: By taking a look, at the live example it looks like something is breaking the HTML by placing `<span="` into your code where the href is meant to be.

Comment: Can you just replace `kingler_theme_show_layout($post_data['post_title']);` by `echo $post_data['post_title']`to see if it works like that. It's 20 lines before the end of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you view source on the HTML page you will see the a span tag within the anchor tag before the href.

```
<a <span="" class="thin">href="http://www.omni-techinfo.com/index.php/product/plaxton-dash-panel-primo/"</a>
```

The offending line may be found in the file *templates/_parts/post-featured.php*
or perhaps it's within the $post_data itself.